# Why can I log to PhpMyAdmin when password is incorrect in db config?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have configured for the first time PhpMyAdmin with Nginx.

During the initial configuration process, I left empty the password field in order to generate a random value.

After that, I logged into mysql as root and changed manually the password for the user phpmyadmin. At that moment I didn't notice that I also had to change the password in the config-db.php.

Then after a successful log into PhpMyAdmin I encountered the following error:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I was confused because I could log in without problems and I could see the databases and much more info.

After searching for a long time, I realize that I had to change the password in the config-db.php and after entering the new password, the message disappeared.

I feel intrigued for how PhpMyAdmin seems to work well even when the password is wrong set in the config file.

Anyone knows how it works?

Comment: If you leave password empty, usually that means a blank password allows you to log in.

Comment: Don't have empty password. Just the password of phpmyadmin mysql user is different from the password in config-db.php